# pull JSON data from the SOAP with Swift Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, soap, alamofire

I am trying to pull JSON data from the SOAP web service. I'm using the Swift Alamofire Library. I get an error, can you help me with how to do it?

```
Alamofire.request("http://service.ceylaner.com.tr/suntech/HotelApps_WebServices.asmx").responseJSON { response in
    print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")
    print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))")
    print("Result: \(response.result)")

    if let json = response.result.value {
        print("JSON: \(json)")
    }

    if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)  {
        print("Data: \(utf8Text)")
    }
}
```

**The code output is as follows.**

**The web service brings the page that the link is to but I want to get json data. I am looking for a way to get the json data from the SOAP web service.**

```
Request: Optional(http://service.ceylaner.com.tr/suntech/HotelApps_WebServices.asmx)
Response: Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x618000025c00> { URL: http://service.ceylaner.com.tr/suntech/HotelApps_WebServices.asmx } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "private, max-age=0";
    "Content-Length" = 6927;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Fri, 04 Aug 2017 12:18:51 GMT";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/10.0";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
} })
Result: FAILURE
Data: 

<html>

    <head><link rel="alternate" type="text/xml" href="/suntech/HotelApps_WebServices.asmx?disco" />

    <style type="text/css">

        BODY { color: #000000; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; }
        #content { margin-left: 30px; font-size: .70em; padding-bottom: 2em; }
        A:link { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; }
        A:visited { color: #6699cc; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; }
        A:active { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; }
        A:hover { color: cc3300; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; }
        P { color: #000000; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 12px; font-family: Verdana; }
        pre { background-color: #e5e5cc; padding: 5px; font-family: Courier New; font-size: x-small; margin-top: -5px; border: 1px #f0f0e0 solid; }
        td { color: #000000; font-family: Verdana; font-size: .7em; }
        h2 { font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 25px; margin-bottom: 10px; border-top: 1px solid #003366; margin-left: -15px; color: #003366; }
        h3 { font-size: 1.1em; color: #000000; margin-left: -15px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; }
        ul { margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 20px; }
        ol { margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 20px; }
        li { margin-top: 10px; color: #000000; }
        font.value { color: darkblue; font: bold; }
        font.key { color: darkgreen; font: bold; }
        font.error { color: darkred; font: bold; }
        .heading1 { color: #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 26px; font-weight: normal; background-color: #003366; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: -30px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-left: 15px; width: 105%; }
        .button { background-color: #dcdcdc; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 1em; border-top: #cccccc 1px solid; border-bottom: #666666 1px solid; border-left: #cccccc 1px solid; border-right: #666666 1px solid; }
        .frmheader { color: #000000; background: #dcdcdc; font-family: Verdana; font-size: .7em; font-weight: normal; border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdcdc; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; }
        .frmtext { font-family: Verdana; font-size: .7em; margin-top: 8px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 32px; }
        .frmInput { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 1em; }
        .intro { margin-left: -15px; }

    </style>

    <title>
    HotelApps_WebServices Web Hizmeti
</title></head>

  <body>

    <div id="content">

      <p class="heading1">HotelApps_WebServices</p><br>



      <span>

          <p class="intro">Aşağıdaki işlemler desteklenmektedir. Tam bir tanımlama için lütfen <a href="HotelApps_WebServices.asmx?WSDL">Hizmet Tanımını</a> gözden geçirin. </p>


              <ul>

              <li>
                <a href="HotelApps_WebServices.asmx?op=BI_WebLink">BI_WebLink</a>


              </li>
              <p>

              <li>
                <a href="HotelApps_WebServices.asmx?op=GetCameraList">GetCameraList</a>


              </li>
              <p>

              <li>
                <a href="HotelApps_WebServices.asmx?op=GetHotels">GetHotels</a>


              </li>
              <p>

              <li>
                <a href="HotelApps_WebServices.asmx?op=GetInfo">GetInfo</a>


              </li>
              <p>

              <li>
                <a href="HotelApps_WebServices.asmx?op=GetInfo_Photo">GetInfo_Photo</a>


              </li>
              <p>

              <li>
                <a href="HotelApps_WebServices.asmx?op=GetMainMenu">GetMainMenu</a>


              </li>
              <p>

              <li>
                <a href="HotelApps_WebServices.asmx?op=GetSubMenu">GetSubMenu</a>


              </li>
              <p>

              <li>
                <a href="HotelApps_WebServices.asmx?op=HelloWorld">HelloWorld</a>


              </li>
              <p>

              </ul>

      </span>




    <span>

    </span>

      <span>
          <hr>
          <h3>Bu web hizmeti, varsayılan ad alanı olarak http://tempuri.org/ kullanıyor.</h3>
          <h3>Öneri: Varsayılan ad alanını XML Web hizmeti genel kullanıma açılmadan önce değiştirin.</h3>
          <p class="intro">Her XML Web hizmetinin, istemci uygulamalarının kendisini Web üzerindeki diğer hizmetlerden ayırt edebilmesi için benzersiz bir ad alanı olmalıdır. Geliştirilmekte olan XML Web hizmetleri için http://tempuri.org/ adresi kullanılabilir. Ancak yayımlanmış XML Web hizmetleri daha kalıcı bir ad alanı kullanmalıdır.</p>
          <p class="intro">XML Web hizmetiniz sizin denetiminizde olan bir ad alanı tarafından tanımlanmalıdır. Örneğin şirketinizin Internet etki alanı adını ad alanının bir parçası olarak kullanabilirsiniz. Pek çok XML Web hizmeti ad alanı URL gibi görünse de, Web üzerindeki gerçek kaynakları işaret etmeleri gerekmez. (XML Web hizmeti ad alanları, URI'lerdir.)</p>
          <p class="intro">ASP.NET kullanılarak oluşturulan XML Web hizmetlerinde, varsayılan ad alanını değiştirmek için WebService özniteliğinin Namespace özelliği kullanılabilir. WebService özniteliği, XML Web hizmeti yöntemlerini içeren sınıf için geçerli bir özniteliktir. Aşağıda ad alanını "http://microsoft.com/webservices/" olarak belirleyen bir kod örneği görülüyor:</p>
          <p class="intro">C#</p>
          <pre>[WebService(Namespace="http://microsoft.com/webservices/")]
public class MyWebService {
    // uygulama
}</pre>
          <p class="intro">Visual Basic</p>
          <pre>&lt;WebService(Namespace:="http://microsoft.com/webservices/")&gt; Public Class MyWebService
    ' uygulama
End Class</pre>

          <p class="intro">C++</p>
          <pre>[WebService(Namespace="http://microsoft.com/webservices/")]
public ref class MyWebService {
    // uygulama
};</pre>
          <p class="intro">XML ad alanları hakkında daha fazla bilgi için <a href="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/">XML'de ad alanları</A> ile ilgili W3C önerilerine bakın.</p>
          <p class="intro">WSDL konusunda daha fazla bilgi için, <a href="http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl">WSDL Belirtimi'ne</a> bakın.</p>
          <p class="intro">URI'ler hakkında daha fazla bilgi için, <a href="http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt">RFC 2396</a> belgesine bakın.</p>
      </span>




  </body>
</html>
```

I'm checking my web service from the Charles program. The json data comes in the xml tag.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9Zqs.png)

Comment: Please also post the error

Comment: I added the code output. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: The response of the server is not JSON, it's HTML, so it's not clear to me why you would try to parse this as JSON...

Comment: I am trying to get data from this web service, by sending method and parameter

Comment: Do you have control over the webservice?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because you forgot to add in info.plist row
[image]

Comment: Thanks Dmytro, I checked the split joint

Comment: I added at info.plist.